# How to diagnose website accessibility issues?

Tags: nginx

So I have a website, [juerix.com](http://juerix.com). I have been having complaints about some mobile users not being able to access the site.

I checked the nginx access log file and it looks like it's responding correctly. I try to access the website myself and it works as expected. How do I diagnose an issue like this one? The error log file is empty.

I asked the user if they can access other sites and they can so not internet issues.

My website uses websockets if that makes a difference.

I understand this is a super general question and there can be various reasons why this is happening. I would like to know the steps I can take, (*ideally without having to have access to the device having the problem, ideally, but if required then it's required*) to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have access to affected device.

If you are using websockets check you websockets server log if this clients connects.

If you cannot access client device, get as many as possible data like (phone name, android (or other os) version, used web browser etc.

... and what is the error on device (it is a blank white page or error message) ?

Comment: Something like browserstack will give you access to real devices via the web, if that helps with the debugging efforts mentioned above.  If you have access to a device, you can hook up your browser's developer tools via USB debugging and see what's going on client side.

Comment: Its a blank white page

Comment: So if your website sends content by websocket you must check if the client connects to ws server. Seriously try to fetch more information about used device and software.

Comment: Nginx access logs tell me the browser, device and os present on the system. In devices it tells me an iphone but not which iphone or a nexus but not which nexus. I have this info. The affected device, an iphone 5 running ios8 using the safari browser. I'll try to get my hands on the device or a similar device and check if there is something